# How to correctly queue image manipulation in laravel with beanstalkd while uploading to Amazon S3?

Tags: laravel, amazon-s3, beanstalkd

I'm doing some tests with laravel by loading images to Amazon S3 and queuing image manipulation with beanstalkd. Please note that this is just testing.

Here is my implementation:

// routes.php

```
Route::post('/', function()
{
    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), array(
        'title' => 'required',
        'file'  => 'required|mimes:jpeg,jpg,png',
    ));

    if( $validator->fails() )
    {
        return Redirect::to('/');
    }

    // Upload File
    $file = Input::file('file');

    $now = new DateTime;
    $hash = md5( $file->getClientOriginalName().$now->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') );
    $key = $hash.'.'.$file->getClientOriginalExtension();

    $s3 = AWS::createClient('s3');

    $s3->putObject(array(
        'Bucket'      => 'bellated',
        'Key'         => $key,
        'SourceFile'  => $file->getRealPath(),
        'ContentType' => $file->getClientMimeType(),
    ));

    // Create job
    Queue::push('\Proc\Worker\ImageProcessor', array(
        'bucket'   => 'bellated',
        'hash'     => $hash,
        'key'      => $key,
        'ext'      => $file->getClientOriginalExtension(),
        'mimetype' => $file->getClientMimeType(),
    ));

    Log::info('queue processed');

    return Redirect::to('/complete');
});
```

// image processor

```
<?php namespace Proc\Worker;

use Imagine\Gd\Imagine;
use Imagine\Image\Box;

class ImageProcessor {

    protected $width;
    protected $height;
    protected $image;

    public function fire($job, $data)
    {
           $s3 = \AWS::createClient('s3');



        try {
   $response = $s3->getObject(array(
            'Bucket'      => $data['bucket'],
            'Key'         => $data['key'],
        ));
} catch (Exception $e) {
   return; 
}

        $imagine = new Imagine();
        $image = $imagine->load( (string)$response->get('Body') );

        $size = new Box(100, 100);
        $thumb = $image->thumbnail($size);

        $s3->putObject(array(
            'Bucket'      => 'bellated',
            'Key'         => $data['hash'].'_100x100.'.$data['ext'],
            'Body'        => $thumb->get($data['ext']),
            'ContentType' => $data['mimetype'],
        ));



    }

}
```

When I have 'sync' as queue - everything works fine and I get both images (original and resized) in Amazon, but after I switched to 'beanstlakd' and run php artisan queue:listen I keep getting this error:

```
Next exception 'Aws\S3\Exception\S3Exception' 
  with message 'Error executing "GetObject" 
  on "https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/bellated/cd05ec14f7a19047828d7ed79d192ee3.jpg";
 AWS HTTP error:  
 Client error: 404 NoSuchKey 
 (client): The specified key does not exist. - 
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Error>
      <Code>NoSuchKey</Code>
      <Message>The specified key does not exist.</Message>
      <Key>cd05ec14f7a19047828d7ed79d192ee3.jpg</Key>
      <RequestId>9390AD2904820C3E</RequestId> 
      <HostId>
        nZK1ivZn3bs6xy0S/tGe+A7yoZgKKccLpUDObKuwS2Zmi8LXUgFI5JpkQWCkwchCw6tgW7jyvGE=
      </HostId>
    </Error>'
  in /home/vagrant/Code/laravel/vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php/src/WrappedHttpHandler.php:152
```

Any ideas on what might be causing this or how could I proceed on this?

Comment: What version of laravel are you using?

Comment: 5.1  - I just have to find out now how to debug or what is the difference when running this console command.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are setting your s3 key to you file name which might be causeing you grief.

```
    $s3->putObject(array(
        'Bucket'      => 'bellated',
        'Key'         => $data['hash'].'_100x100.'.$data['ext'],
        'Body'        => $thumb->get($data['ext']),
        'ContentType' => $data['mimetype'],
    ));
```

The error makes me think this.

```
Client error: 404 NoSuchKey 
(client): The specified key does not exist. - 
<Key>cd05ec14f7a19047828d7ed79d192ee3.jpg</Key>
```

In general, it looks like you are doing this the hard way. I am not sure how to make your code work, but Laravel does a lot of what you are trying to do right out of the box.

Here is how I have done what you are trying to do.

You need to set up your environment.

**.env**

```
    S3_KEY=MYKEYMYKEYMYKEYMYKEY
    S3_SECRET=MYSECRETMYSECRETMYSECRETMYSECRETMYSECRET
    S3_REGION=us-east-1
    S3_BUCKET=bucketname
```

**config/filesystem.php**

```
    <?php
    return [
        'default' => 'local',
        'cloud' => 's3',
        'disks' => [
            'local' => [
                'driver' => 'local',
                'root'   => storage_path().'/app',
            ],
        's3' => [
            'driver' => 's3',
            'key'    => env('S3_KEY'),
            'secret' => env('S3_SECRET'),
            'region' => env('S3_REGION'),
            'bucket' => env('S3_BUCKET'),
        ],
        ],
    ];
```

**routes.php** Quick test

```
    Route::get('s3',function(){
        $success = Storage::disk('s3')->put('hello.txt','hello');
        return ($success)?'Yeay!':'Boo Hoo';
    });
```

I know that this is with a text file but it is the same.

How I would handle the Queueing is by using [Laravel's Job](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queues#writing-job-classes) (it use to be command).

At the terminal type which will make a app/Jobs/NewJob.php file.

```
php artisan make:job NewJob --queued
```

Set up your job like this.

**NewJob.php**

```
    <?php

    namespace App\Jobs;

    use ...;

    class NewJob extends Job implements SelfHandling, ShouldQueue
    {
        public $content;
        public $path;

        use InteractsWithQueue, SerializesModels;
        public function __construct($content, $path)
        {
            $this->content = $content;
            $this->path = $path;
        }

        public function handle()
        {
            Storage::disk('s3')->put($this->path,$this->content)
        }
    }
```

And your controller something like this

```
    <?php

    namespace App\Http\Controllers;

    use ...;

    class ImageController extends Controller
    {
        public function sendImage($content, $path)
        {
            $this->dispatch(new NewJob($content, $path));
        }
    }
```